# How to remotely execute Python with more than one module through Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, python-import

## Introduction

I want to run Python code (`test.py`) on a remote host with Ansible. This has not been a problem until I pulled out some functions into another module.

When running a playbook with `ansible-playbook test.yml` (contents below, some details removed):

```
- name: Perform tests
  hosts: ...
  vars_files:
      ...
  tasks:
      - name: run test script
        script: "{{ playbook_dir }}/scripts/test.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<removed>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1515175369.61-59422518925475/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    import utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

However, running `python scripts/test.py` on the target machine runs without a hitch.

## Details

Here's my directory layout:

```
+ scripts/
   - __init__.py
   - test.py
   - utils.py
```

Inside `test.py`, I have this line:

```
import utils
```

## Question

*How can I import the `utils` module from inside test.py?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I import the utils module from inside test.py?

You need to transfer all the files to the target machine (with a `copy` module) and execute the `python` command on the target machine (with a `command` module and `chdir` option).

You can’t do it using the `script` module — it doesn’t transfer files other than the one given in the argument.